# What does "as small as a fraction of an angstrom" mean?

Tags: terminology, units, measurements

I was reading my school textbook in which the following statement was given:

> The resolution of such an electron microscope is limited finally by the fact that electrons can also behave as waves! (You will learn more about this in class XII). **The wavelength of an electron can be as small as a fraction of an angstrom.**

What does the highlighted statement mean?

Does it mean $1 \:\mathrm{angstrom}/100$?

Or $1\:\mathrm{angstrom}/1\:\mathrm{angstrom}$?

Basically, I just want to know how will the above statement can be represented mathematically?

Comment: This appears to be less a question about physics and more about the English language: "as small as a fraction of an X" means effectively the same as "smaller than an X".

Comment: How will write it mathematically? 10^-20 angstrom?

Comment: It is spelled [ångström](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m).

Comment: @SakshamSharma Well, you'd write it as $10^{-20} Å$  and it is certainly is a **fraction** of an angstrom. And no, "1 Angstrom/1Angstrom" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Is fraction of anything be represented as divided by  what equals to in numerator of the fraction? In this case fraction of an angstrom 10^-20/10^-20?

Comment: @SakshamSharma In this context, a fraction refers to any number which is smaller than $1$.  $10^{-20}$ is a fraction in itself. $10^{-20}/10^{-20}$ is not a fraction. So you need to write it as $10^{-20}Å$ and not $10^{-20}/10^{-20}Å$.

Comment: @Blue I think in this context it simply means anything lesser than 1 Angstrom? Isn't it? Because 1 Angstrom is itself a fraction?

Comment: @SakshamSharma Yes

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/231311/

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Simple.2C_common.2C_or_vulgar_fractions

Answer (score 4):

This construction is a slightly fuzzy use of the English language, and it does not have any specific, definite meaning.

In essence, what it's conveying is that the wavelength $\lambda$ in question can be smaller than 1 angstrom, 
$$
\lambda < 1 \: Å.
$$
However, it does not really specify how much smaller that wavelength will be. Typically you'd use that language for situations in which $\lambda \approx 0.1 \: Å$ is achievable, going down to maybe things like $\lambda \approx 0.001 \: Å$, but the further down you get, the less applicable that language becomes (so, say, something like $\lambda \approx 10^{-20} \: Å$ would *not* be included in that usage, as it's just too small). Since the construction is fuzzy, though, there is no hard bottom at which the length is too small to qualify.

---

And as for the fraction $1\: Å/1 \: Å$, that is a dimensionless number and not a length, so a wavelength cannot be equal to that.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that the de Broglie wavelength of an electron can be less than an angstrom